# Leibniz rule with unknown orders of imput

Tags: physics, algebraic-manipulation, functional-style

I'm trying to find a simple way to define
a **bilinear and Leibniz** functional/map "$B(\cdot,\cdot)$", that eats two functions $f(x),f(y)$ or products theirof and produces the following,
 $$
        B(f(x),f(y))=f(x**y-y**x) \,,
 $$

where "$**$" is a non-commutative product that's un-important for my question.

The problem I have is making the map $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ obey the Leibniz rule
$$
    B(f(x_1)f(x_2)...f(x_n),f(y))=\sum_if(x_1)...f(x_{i-1})B(f(x_i),f(y))f(x_{i+1})..f(x_n) \,.
$$

I have read this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155516/operator-satisfies-leibniz-rule) and tried the following code to implement just for Leibniz rule

```
B[f[x_], f[y_]] := f[x ** y - y ** x]
B[f[x_]*f[y_], f[z_]] := B[f[x], f[z]]*f[y] + f[x]*B[f[y], f[z]]
```

But the above code doesn't seem to understand how to handle power imputs of $f(x)$ with the same argument $x$, e.g. $f(x)^2$, and higher order products like $f(x)f(y)f(z)$.
For example if I evaluate

```
B[f[a]^2, f[e]]
B[f[a]*f[b]*f[c], f[e]]
```

Mathematica doesn't seem to know what to do.

I guess it's because I only told Mathematica how to handle two imputs in one slot of $B(\cdot,\cdot)$. But since I am going to be manipulating higher order products of $f(x)$, how should I define the map $B$ without making one definition for each order of product/power of the imput function?

PS: The problem also comes up when I try to implement Bilinearity for the map $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

`B[f[x_],f[y_]]:=f[x**y-y**x];
B[x_Times,y_]:=Sum[ReplacePart[x,{i}:>B[x[[i]],y]],{i,Length[x]}];
B[Power[x_,y_],z_]:=y*Power[x,y-1]*B[x,z];`

Comment: Thanks! I tried a few examples it worked out pretty well. May I ask what "x_Times" means in the 2nd line? And if you have the 2nd line, why do you still need the 3rd? I am trying to understand this well enough to impletement the bilinearity of B. Thanks!

Comment: @JDING  `x_Times` is a pattern which represents an expression with head `Times`. Similarly, `Power[x_, y_]` is pattern represents an expression with head `Power`. For more detail, you may check the document for `Pattern` and `Blank`. Mathematically, x^2 can be identified with x*x. However, these are two different expressions in Mathematica. The former is of head `Power`, while the latter is of head `Times` (Mathematica would automatically replace `x*x` by `x^2`, but not vice versa). That's why we need the third line.